# Совмещение Java и frontend

Tags: javascript, java, frontend

Допустим, написал я на spring boote серверную часть, регистрацию пользователя, работа с базой данных и тд. это все у меня отображается через jsp. Захотел я сделать свою страницу покрасивее, научился верстать страницы, добавил красивые анимации через Angular и вот вопрос - как по-правильному это все связать. 
Знаю что есть Gulp, что-то вроде Mavena только для фронта, но как связать это все по-академически, красиво, что-бы данные с формы высылались на сервер а таблица на странице подгружала с сервера данные. Или вообще бросить java и начать учить node?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы разрабатывать подобные приложения необходимо иметь представление об архитектурном стиле [REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST). Основной принцип работы подобных приложений изображен на рис.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пояснение:** как видно из рисунка приложение "разбивается на два приложения":

- клиентское приложение (написанное на Angular, ... и отвечает за "внешний вид" веб приложения)
- серверное приложение (написанное, например, на Spring Boot и отвечает за данные нашего приложения. Здесь содержаться контроллеры, сервисы, репозитории, сущности. Основная задача серверного приложения: достать данные из базы и вернуть их (HTTP ответом))

Конечно это поверхностный взгляд. Есть замечательная книга [AngularJS for Java Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077XX9CS5), в которой описывается работа приложения, состоящего из "клиента" и "сервера".

Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо большое!